# Kubernetes terminating pods without a clear reason in the logs

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to know why Kubernetes is terminating pods?

If I go to `Logging` in the Google console, the only message I can find related to this event is:

```
shutting down, got signal: Terminated
```

Also, the pods in status `Terminating` are never being terminated, a few of them are in this status for more than 24 hours now.

I'm not using `livenessProbes` or `readinessProbes`.

I am using `terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30`

---

EDIT: added the result of `kubectl describe pod <podname>` for the pod that is the `Terminating` status for 9 hours as of now:

```
Name:               storeassets-5383k
Namespace:          default
Node:               gke-recommendation-engin-default-pool-c9b136a8-0qms/10.132.0.85
Start Time:         Sat, 11 Mar 2017 06:27:32 +0000
Labels:             app=storeassets
                deployment=ab08dc44070ffbbceb69ff6a5d99ae61
                version=v1
Status:             Terminating (expires Tue, 14 Mar 2017 01:30:48 +0000)
Termination Grace Period:   30s
Reason:             NodeLost
Message:            Node gke-recommendation-engin-default-pool-c9b136a8-0qms which was running pod storeassets-5383k is unresponsive
IP:             10.60.3.7
Controllers:            ReplicationController/storeassets
Containers:
  storeassets:
    Container ID:   docker://7b38f1de0321de4a5f2b484f5e2263164a32e9019b275d25d8823de93fb52c30
    Image:      eu.gcr.io/<project-name>/recommendation-content-realtime
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:9e8cf1b743f94f365745a011702a4ae1c2e636ceaaec4dd8d36fef6f787aefe7
    Port:
    Command:
      python
      -m
      realtimecontent.storeassets
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    State:      Running
      Started:      Sat, 11 Mar 2017 06:27:33 +0000
    Ready:      True
    Restart Count:  0
    Volume Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-qwfs4 (ro)
    Environment Variables:
      RECOMMENDATION_PROJECT:       <project-name>
      RECOMMENDATION_BIGTABLE_ID:   recommendation-engine
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:   recommendation-engine-credentials.json
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Initialized   True
  Ready     False
  PodScheduled  True
Volumes:
  default-token-qwfs4:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-qwfs4
QoS Class:  Burstable
Tolerations:    <none>
No events.
```

Comment: Why do you not useing the probes? What's the output of 'kubectl describe pod <HANGING-POD>'

Comment: I'm using probes against application that expose APIs, but this specific pod that is terminating doesn't have an API. Nevertheless, the command you suggested is helping me already. It looks like the application is just terminating with status code 0 and the pod is restarting. Unfortunately this information don't seem to show in the Kubernetes logs.

Comment: Good to heare ;-)

Comment: @Aleks, I added the details you asked for in the question

Comment: I think this is the reason why the pod was terminated 'Reason:             NodeLost
Message:            Node gke-recommendation-engin-default-pool-c9b136a8-0qms which was running pod storeassets-5383k is unresponsive
'

Comment: yes, and I can see that in the logs now, which is good. The problem now is that this is just the symptom. Why the pod is not being terminated and why nodes are getting lost is still a mystery. Sounds like a bug in Kubernetes/GoogleCloud.

Comment: Maybe the liveness probe can bring some light into this